# Api key required when uploading video via resumable upload for youtube data v3

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am writing an android app that uploads videos to user's youtube account. Using the account manager I obtain the authtoken for the youtubeupload scope and use a  resumable upload session to upload content onto the user account. Here despite providing the authtoken , the app is denied access or Quota limit exceeded error messages are see when the upload is done.

However when the api key is part of the request (in addition to the authtoken) the upload works fine.

Since the user is already authenticated with the auth token, and no google api's are used, I don't understand the need for an api key in this usecase.

[This](https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=PARTS&key=API_KEY) is url that works for me

Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Simple API access on your [dev console](http://code.google.com/apis/console).
Create one with your [SHA1].

Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Android apps:
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ; com.android.example [SHA1 ; package name]

You also need another one installed application for Android as well if you still want to use your api key.

Comment: Thanks!.But what I don't understand is the need for an api key when the authorization token is used. If this is to track usage quota per app, how can insert/list and thus quota usage be tracked per user instead of the app?

Comment: If you set your console as described above, you won't need API key

Comment: There is a YouTube Direct Lite Android example, you can see the Authorization there. https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have setup my API console. The API KEY I have to use in my upload uri is the one listed here.  Key for Android apps (with certificates)  API key:[api key,this is the key I need to specify in my url for the upload to succeed]  Android apps:Any app allowed  Activated on:date  Activated by:x@gmail.com – you.  In the YouTube Direct Lite example, the upload url is [this](http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads) which is v2 instead of [this](https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=PARTS)